# Thread scheduling C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

```
 #include <pthread.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #define NUM_THREADS  4
 #define TCOUNT 5
 #define COUNT_LIMIT 13

 int     done = 0;
 int    count = 0;
 int     thread_ids[4] = {0,1,2,3};
 int thread_runtime[4] = {0,5,4,1};
 pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;
 pthread_cond_t count_threshold_cv;

 void *inc_count(void *t)
 {
   int i;
   long my_id = (long)t;
   long run_time = thread_runtime[my_id];
   if (my_id==2 && done==0) {
     for(i=0; i<5 ; i++) {
       if (i==4) {
         done = 1;
       }
       pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
       count++;

       if (count == COUNT_LIMIT) {
         pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv);
         printf("inc_count(): thread %ld, count = %d  Threshold reached.\n",
           my_id, count);
       }
       printf("inc_count(): thread %ld, count = %d, unlocking mutex\n", my_id, count);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
     }
   }

   if (my_id==3 && done==1) {
     for(i=0; i< 4 ; i++) {
       if (i==3) {
         done = 2;
       }
       pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
       count++;

       if (count == COUNT_LIMIT) {
         pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv);
         printf("inc_count(): thread %ld, count = %d  Threshold reached.\n",
           my_id, count);
       }
       printf("inc_count(): thread %ld, count = %d, unlocking mutex\n", my_id, count);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
     }
   }

   if (my_id==4 && done==2) {
     for(i=0; i<8; i++) {
       pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
       count++;
       if (count == COUNT_LIMIT) {
         pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv);
         printf("inc_count(): thread %ld, count = %d  Threshold reached.\n",
           my_id, count);
       }
       printf("inc_count(): thread %ld, count = %d, unlocking mutex\n", my_id, count);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
     }
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
 }

 void *watch_count(void *t)
 {
   long my_id = (long)t;

   printf("Starting watch_count(): thread %ld\n", my_id);
   pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
   if (count<COUNT_LIMIT) {
     pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv, &count_mutex);
     printf("watch_count(): thread %ld Condition signal received.\n", my_id);
     count += 125;
     printf("watch_count(): thread %ld count now = %d.\n", my_id, count);
   }
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
 }

 int main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   int i, rc;
   long t1=1, t2=2, t3=3, t4=4;
   pthread_t threads[4];
   pthread_attr_t attr;

   pthread_mutex_init(&count_mutex, NULL);
   pthread_cond_init (&count_threshold_cv, NULL);
   pthread_attr_init(&attr);
   pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
   pthread_create(&threads[0], &attr, watch_count, (void *)t1);
   pthread_create(&threads[1], &attr, inc_count, (void *)t2);
   pthread_create(&threads[2], &attr, inc_count, (void *)t3);
   pthread_create(&threads[3], &attr, inc_count, (void *)t4);

   for (i=0; i<NUM_THREADS; i++) {
     pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
   }
   printf ("Main(): Waited on %d  threads. Done.\n", NUM_THREADS);

   pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
   pthread_mutex_destroy(&count_mutex);
   pthread_cond_destroy(&count_threshold_cv);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
 }
```

So this code creates 4 threads.  Thread 1 keeps track of the count value while the other 3 increment the count value. The run time is the number of times the thread will increment the count value.  I have a done value that allows the first thread to increment the count value first until its run time is up.. so its like a First Come First Serve.

My question is: Is there a better way of implementing this?  I have read about SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR. I guess I dont know how to implement them into this code or if it can be

Comment: Hmm, I'm still missing what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to schedule the threads differently and effectively. Does that help? I want to use SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: Your inc_count function is very nasty with those if blocks. It would be far better to have a different function for each thread.

Comment: Also your 'done' variable is not locked. The compiler is free to stick that in a register and your other threads will never, ever see it. It could happen.

Comment: And yup, if the thread creation order is just a *little bit* off, the program locks up because done never gets set to the right value.

Comment: Congrats, you have at least two really difficult to debug threading heisenbugs in 100 lines of code. :)

Comment: i know what you mean about the if functions... I want to clean that up ... right now I wanted to get thread 2 3 and 4 to run in order... I want to get rid of the if statements.

Comment: @MRP: If you want code to run in order then do not use threads. There is no benefit for you.
But, if you wanted to anyway, you need a lock per thread. Before starting the threads, lock all the per-thread locks. Have each thread lock its thread lock as the first thing. Then you unlock a thread lock to release that thread to run.

Comment: i have to use threads... I will give it another go

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly you are trying to produce sort of a pipeline where the next thread picks up where the previous one stops. The cleanest solution in this case is to use **binary semaphores**.

Say you have four threads. Create four semaphores with initial values of `{1, 0, 0, 0}`. Assign semaphore per thread and have each thread `down` its semaphore upon start and `up` *the next semaphore* (modulo number of threads) in the chain. Start all threads - the first acquires its semaphore immediately, does its work, other threads block on their semaphores. First thread finishes work, `up`s the next semaphore, thus waking up the next thread, then loops to the beginning, etc. etc.

I think the real-time scheduling classes you mention have nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Some notes on your code:

- variables not protected by locks that signal state change between threads (like `done` here) have to be **`volatile`**, so compiler does not optimize them out of the loops.
- you can use thread function argument to pass more complex information to a thread, say a pointer to a structure.
- you always want to call `pthread_cond_wait` *in a loop* where loop condition checks the thing you wait on. This is to avoid [**spurious wakeups**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup).
- you always want to call `pthread_cond_signal` either outside of the lock, or as the very last thing before unlock. This is to avoid wasted wakeup/sleep cycles in the waiting threads - they wake up, find the mutex still locked, block (sleep) again.
- avoid many threads contending on the same lock, this leads to [**thundering herd**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem) problem.
- *always* check return values of the `pthread` calls.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah some of it makes sense.  I do think you are right in using semaphores.

Comment: +1 from me for semaphores. -1 for recommending volatile for *anything*. So it's a wash.

Comment: @Zan: `volatile` in practice is perfectly fine for signaling "one-way"/edge state changes like shutdown flags. It does not of coarse apply to any synchronization/locking/mutual exclusion scenarios.

Comment: @Nikolai: No it isn't fine. Nothing in any specification requires volatile changes to become visible to other CPUs in the system. It works on x86 hardware. You can't claim it is portable though.

Comment: @Zan: That's why I don't like this discussion. I work on a real computers, real OSes, specific compilers. I learned not to trust specifications and test my stuff. BTW, it works on sparc too :)

Comment: @Nikolai: Well just remember this when it doesn't work on a machine that requires an explicit locked cache write to get it onto the other CPUs. Then you will know how to fix it. :)

Comment: @Zan: I believe you, there's ton of fun hardware out there, but then wouldn't normal shared data protected by locks have to be handled in a special way too? What specification requires these changes to propagate anywhere? Should I assume full cache flush with every lock operation?

Comment: I made a new post.. I cleaned up the code.  I tried using semaphores to do a RR scheduling, but I need to create a dispatcher.. Im not sure of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR are real-time scheduling classes. They are not for use in ordinary code. You should be able to do most of anything you need using pthread mutexes.

Comment: ok.. so then I would have to create an algorithm for RR then, right?